# Microsoft CRM SDK use Guid as query condition value

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I need to use the Mircosoft CRM SDK to pull a group of addresses based on the `parentid` stored in each of the address entities. This `parentid` naturally corresponds to the `GUID` of the parent record.

I've built this query two ways: first I simply place the `GUID` in the `condition.Values` property, and second I tried using and `EntityReference`.

If I simply use the `GUID` the query completes but I receive no results. If I use the `EntityReference` I get the following exception:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:query. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference' with data contract name 'EntityReference:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types

I've also tried building the query using two different methods, however I get the same results along the same lines of `GUID` input into the condition value.

If I open the Microsoft Dynamics web page for the account I'm working on, I can clearly see that the address has been entered.

[image]

How do you go about including `GUID` to query on the `parentid`?

**Method One**

```
    ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
    condition.AttributeName = "parentid";
    condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;

    //This works but returns no results
    condition.Values.Add(new EntityReference("account", id));

    //This throws the above exception
    //condition.Values.Add(new EntityReference("account", id));

    ColumnSet column = new ColumnSet(true);
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
    query.ColumnSet = column;
    query.EntityName = "customeraddress";
    query.Criteria.AddCondition(condition);
```

**Method Two**

```
        QueryExpression queryEx = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "customeraddress",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
                Criteria =
                    {
                        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                        Conditions =
                            {
                                new ConditionExpression
                                    {
                                        AttributeName = "parentid",
                                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,

                                        //Works but returns no results
                                        Values = {id}

                                        //Throws exception
                                        //Values = {new EntityReference("account", id)}
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            };
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `QueryByAttribute`?

Comment: Exact same results using either the GUID directly or `EntityReference`

Comment: I guess outside of that the only things I could think of are 1) triple checking the ID you are passing in is actually the ParentID of those CustomerAddress records and 2) making sure the context you are running under has privileges to query those CustomerAddress records (and that it's not security that's preventing you from getting back results). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query addresses in advance find:

[image]

If this results some records then below simple query should have data for u.

```
private EntityCollection getAddresses(Guid AccountID, IOrganizationService service)
{
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("customeraddress");
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentid", ConditionOperator.Equal, AccountID);    
    EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way to fetch this data is by Downloading the FetchXML of that Query from Advanced Find then executing that Fetch Expression and adding the Id as a string :
[image]

```
  string fetchxml= @"  <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
      <entity name="customeraddress">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="line1" />
        <attribute name="city" />
        <attribute name="postalcode" />
        <attribute name="telephone1" />
        <attribute name="customeraddressid" />
        <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
        <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentid" alias="aa">
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="accountid" operator="eq" uitype="account" value="{7EDECF7F-AE71-E511-80EC-3863BB3610E8}" />
          </filter>
        </link-entity>
      </entity>
    </fetch>";

  FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(fetchxml);
  EntityCollection fetchresults = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);
```

You can then replace the Guid value in the fetchxml string with your guid string.